# Android 4.3: Native crash in unkown.unknown

Tags: android, crash, native

I am getting this error on Android 4.3. reported by Google developer console.  My customers complain that the application crashes once they just open it.

Please tell me what I should do. This is not something I can deal with as the errors are not the usual java error messages.

The same error comes from the following Android devices:

HTC One (m7)

Galaxy Note3 (hltetmo)

HTC One max (t6ul)

Galaxy S3 (d2can)

The error :

```
Build fingerprint: 'htc/htc_europe/m7:4.3/JSS15J/264544.1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '3'
pid: 5659, tid: 5673, name: Thread-6011 >>> net.superlinux.generalengineeringpaid <<<
signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 422ea818 r1 00000000 r2 6e09e007 r3 00000000
r4 6bc420f0 r5 69fbffd8 r6 67689198 r7 000042f4
r8 409d21c0 r9 6c495dd4 sl 40a78c48 fp 422ea818
ip 6d1a9c34 sp 6c495da0 lr 00000000 pc 6e09e020 cpsr 600d0030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 d1d1d1d1d1d1d1d1 d3 d1d1d1d1d1d1d1d1
d4 ff00ff00ff00ff00 d5 0004000400040004
d6 0bf40bf40bf40bf4 d7 414000000bf40bf4
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 625bdf88625bdf50 d17 625bdff8625bdfc0
d18 625bdb28625bdaf0 d19 625bdb98625bdb60
d20 625bdc08625bdbd0 d21 625bdc78625bdc40
d22 625bdce8625bdcb0 d23 625bdd58625bdd20
d24 0773000007710000 d25 0777000007750000
d26 000001dd000001dd d27 000001de000001de
d28 0002000000020000 d29 0002000000020000
d30 0001000000010000 d31 0001000000010000
scr 28000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 00001020 /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

code around pc:
6e09e000 6d15d258 f85f0058 68010008 60013101 
6e09e010 692868a9 6d41b138 f8d1b139 290010f4 
6e09e020 aff8f43f 60a9e003 60a9e004 60a9e005 
6e09e030 de00e008 0044f8df f8dfe001 6ef1003c 
6e09e040 1c2d4788 4300e000 47806e70 6bc420fc 
6e09e050 4300e000 47806e70 6bc420f0 00000001 
6e09e060 00000001 00000000 629ae9d0 00000103 
6e09e070 00000001 00000000 6bc420f4 6bc420f0 
6e09e080 6d15d25c f85f005c 68010008 60013101 
6e09e090 f04f68a9 60280000 f2a56868 b170071c 
6e09e0a0 f8dfc703 a108007c 4070f8df 0703f04f 
6e09e0b0 0202f04f e82cf7ff e000e00c f8dfde00 
6e09e0c0 6ef1005c 1c2d4788 f970e000 47806f70 
6e09e0d0 6bfdd8ac f91ce000 47806f70 6bf2aaa4 
6e09e0e0 00010100 00000000 00000000 629a8328 
6e09e0f0 00000002 00000001 6c05f414 00000000 

code around lr:
00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

Comment: Hi, did you find something? I have a similar error.

Comment: I also have a similar error. If you find something please share :)

Answer (score 1):

Sigstkflt suggests that you are running out of memory in a native code. Are you using any native libraries? I would look for any big objects (like bitmaps) being created in native code by malloc().

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS level bug caused by some restrictions on writing to SD card. It seems to happen only on certain devices that received an update to Android 4.4. Check [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-bypass-Android-44-KitKat-external-SD-write-/).

For some strange reason the bug also occurs when you don't even have an SD card and the app isn't even attempting to write anything to it. Putting `android:installLocation="auto"` in the manifest seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is because of Google Play services (6.1.88).
To solve this issue try to add **largeHeap="true"** in Android Manifest file.
For more details, refer this link 
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7187

Comment: How is that issue related to the question?